# Write this SQL query in LINQ to Entity format

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have this sql query need to convert to linq to entity

```
select kv.KeyID, kv.KeyVotID, v.VotID, v.FullName
from E_KeyVot kv
join E_Vot v
on kv.VotID = v.VotID
where kv.KeyID=2
order by v.FullName
```

This what I have tried but I'm sure it is not correct:

```
Public Function GetKeyVot() As IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot)
  Try
     Dim _objQuery As IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot, Ems_Vot) = _
         From a In Context.Ems_KeyVot 
         Join b In Context.Ems_Vot On a.votid Equals b.votid
         Where a.keyid = pub_KeyID
         Order By b.FullName
     Return _objQuery
   Catch ex As Exception
   End Try
 End Function
```

Comment: If you show what you've tried so far, you would likely get more responses. This query is relatively straight forward, so you shouldn't have too much trouble figuring it out.

Comment: This what I have tried but I'm sure it is not correct:

Public Function GetKeyVot() As IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot)
        Try
            Dim _objQuery As IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot, Ems_Vot) = _
                        From a In Context.Ems_KeyVot
                        Join b In Context.Ems_Vot
                        On a.votid Equals b.votid
                        Where a.keyid = pub_KeyID
                        Order By b.FullName

            Return _objQuery

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, the issue you have is that your return types don't agree with the query. The query returns an IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot, Ems_Vot), but your function is expecting an IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot).

In your query, you are projecting values from both tables. Since you can't return an anonymous type from your function, you need to create another class to return the results:

```
Public Class Votes
  Public Property KeyID As Integer
  Public Property KeyVotID As Integer
  Public Property VotID As Integer
  Public Property FullName As String
End Class
```

With that, you can modify your query as follows:

```
 Dim _objQuery As IQueryable(Of Ems_KeyVot, Ems_Vot) = _
     From a In Context.Ems_KeyVot 
     Join b In Context.Ems_Vot On a.votid Equals b.votid
     Where a.keyid = pub_KeyID
     Order By b.FullName
     Select New Votes With { .KeyID = a.KeyID, .KeyVotID = a.KeyVotID, .VotID = b.VotID, .FullName = b.FullName }
```

Also change your function definition to

```
Public Function GetKeyVot() As IQueryable(Of Votes)
```

One other note, I see that you have a try catch block, but you aren't doing anything with the exception. If you can't handle an exception, remove the block and let it bubble up to something that can.

Comment: I don't understand why I should create a Votes class?

Comment: Since you aren't returning values from just one table or the other, you need to project an anonymous type from your query. However, you can't pass an anonymous type as the result of your function because you can't name it (it's anonymous). As a result, you need to project into a type that you can name (Votes).

Comment: It didn't work I get error on the Context line 'Ems_KeyVot' is not a member of System.Web.HttpContext.

Also why they are anonymous? all the properties in the votes class you suggest are existing properties in the other 2 entities/tables KeyVot & Vot.

I'm not able to post more details in her coz number of characters are limited plz check my blog I posted the entity details I am dealing with hope will be more clear:
http://ahmad0darwiche.blogspot.com/2013/07/linq-to-entity-error.html

Comment: For your first error ('is not a member of HttpContext') change the use of Context in the example to use your data context not the http context. Regarding the question of anonymous types, even though the properties are present in the two tables, you can't return two things as the result of a function, you need to transform them into another thing (class) to return them from the function. You can read more about VB Anonymous types at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx